# Multiple filter in columns and rows in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this code after filtering a CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd

data1=pd.read_csv('Report1.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

df = data1[pd.notnull(data1['Assignee'])]

group=(df['type'].value_counts())

print(group)
```

But I'm stuck here when the csv looks like:

```
Type     Assignee        status

request  madan          assigned

ris      madan          resolved

request  kumar          resolved

incide   kumar          assigned

incide   madan          assigned
```

I need output as:

```
madan has 2 assigned and 1 resolved (1  request, 1 ris , 1 inciden)

kumar has 1 assigned and 1 resolved (1 request , 1 incident )
```

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `crosstab` in `pandas`

```
pd.concat([pd.crosstab(df.Assignee, df.status), pd.crosstab(df.Assignee, df.Type)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
          assigned  resolved  incide  request  ris
Assignee
kumar            1         1       1        1    0
madan            2         1       1        1    1
```

Comment: pd.concat([pd.crosstab(df['Assignee+'], df['Status*']), pd.crosstab(df['Assignee+'], df['Case Type*']], axis=1))

Comment: Yes, you are right, df['colname'] is a formal way and df.colname is more of a syntax sugar with limitations in column namings. It is generally not a good idea to include spaces,  `+` or `-` signs in column names since as you experienced the syntax sugar does not work anymore.

Comment: Your first comment is the way :)